# Error Vuex is not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy dando los primeros pasos con `vue` y por eso estoy probando `vuex` y estoy recibiendo el siguiente error:

> ```
>  Error: {
>    "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: Vuex is not defined",
>    "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
>    "lineno": 36,
>    "colno": 23
>    }
> ```

Este es el código previo a integrar ```Vuex``, si lo ejecutan no deberian ver errores en la consola.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Vue -->
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js "></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <titulo></titulo>
    </div>

    <script>
        Vue.component('titulo', {
            template: /*html*/ `
                    <div>
                        <h1>numero</h1>
                    </div>
                `
        });


        new Vue({
            el: '#app',

        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

> El problema ocurre cuando yo quiero integrar `Vuex` siguiendo el ejemplo de la documentación https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Vue y Vuex -->
    <script src=" https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js "></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/es6-promise@4/dist/es6-promise.auto.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app" class="container">
        <titulo></titulo>
    </div>

    <script>
        Vue.component('titulo', {
            template: /*html*/ `
                    <div>
                        <h1>numero</h1>
                    </div>
                `
        });
        
        const store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
        count: 0
         },
        mutations: {
           increment (state) {
           state.count++
           }
          }
        })
        
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            store

        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

El ejemplo que uso lo saqué de la documentación, y da lo mismo si lo agrego como dice ahí, o si lo pongo vació como se indica a continuación. El error es el mismo.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({})
```

> Alguna sugerencia de porqué tengo ese error? Muchas gracias

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿Descargaste la librería y lo importaste en el archivo main.js?

Comment: no, estoy trabajando con un unico archivo html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hace falta añadir la referencia de `Vuex`, tal como lo indica en la [documentación](https://vuex.vuejs.org/installation.html)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```